# Form empty check

Tags: javascript, forms, null

I build a script, that place the text that user type in form on the site. Now I'm trying to check forms. If form is empty then value of form will be not placed on the site. If form is not empty it will place the value of the form on the site. But my script don't work well. Can you check this?

```
if (formtitle.value != null && formdescription.value != null) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var giftinfo = "<div class='gifttext'>";
    giftinfo += "<img class='GiftImage omega' src='" + formimage.value + "'>";
    giftinfo += "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + formtitle.value + "</p>";
    giftinfo += "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + formdescription.value + "</p>";
    giftinfo += "</div>";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "gift";
    div.innerHTML = giftinfo;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
else if (formtitle.value = null && formdescription.value = null) {
    alert("Pola tekstowe są puste!");
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `else if` you need to use `==` or `===` but not `=` which is only used for assignment not comparison. Your don't actually need `else if` anyway given the if you've had before the `else if` is guaranteed to be satisfied.

I would recommend changing your if to check that both `formtitle.value` and `formdescription.value` don't equal either `null` or `undefined` then change your `else if` to just `else`. Your new code would look like this:

```
if (formtitle.value != null && formdescription.value != null && formtitle.value != undefined && formdescription.value != undefined) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var giftinfo = "<div class='gifttext'>";
    giftinfo += "<img class='GiftImage omega' src='" + formimage.value + "'>";
    giftinfo += "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + formtitle.value + "</p>";
    giftinfo += "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + formdescription.value + "</p>";
    giftinfo += "</div>";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "gift";
    div.innerHTML = giftinfo;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
else {
    alert("Pola tekstowe są puste!");
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property for all form fields will always be a string. There is no sense in checking for null because it will never be null. Instead, check for an "empty" string:

```
event.preventDefault();

if (!isEmpty(formtitle.value) && !isEmpty(formdescription.value)) {
    var giftinfo = "<div class='gifttext'>"
                 +     "<img class='GiftImage omega' src='" + formimage.value + "'>"
                 +     "<p class='GiftTitle'>" + formtitle.value + "</p>"
                 +     "<p class='GiftDescription'>" + formdescription.value + "</p>"
                 + "</div>";
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "gift";
    div.innerHTML = giftinfo;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
else {
    alert("Pola tekstowe są puste!");
}


// somewhere in the global scope:
function isEmpty(value) {
    return /^\s*$/.test(value);
}
```